# How can I group this list of elements using threads?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, list

I have a list like this:

```
[Header/Element]
[Element]
[Element]
[Header]
[Element]
[Element]
[Element]
[Header]
[Element]
...
[Element/Header]
```

So this list could or could not have a [Header] in the first position and might not contain also a [Header] element at the end.

I've been assigned to create an algorithm to group this elements under every header, so, the appearance of a header can start a new group with all elements below corresponding to this group. If the first element of the list is not a header (which can be a possibility) then a default group should be used, so all elements until the next header get in this group. The same for elements at the end: there might not be a header that tells you where to end/start a group. So far, not very difficult to do linearly iterating through the entire list.

The real question is, does anyone knows how can do this grouping algorithm but using multiple threads? The reason I want multiple threads is because this list of headers/elements can be very large so I thought that it would be a good idea to have many threads grouping at different parts of the list.

The problem is that I have no idea what could be the procedure to do this and how could I synchronize the threads, specially with the way the list has been layed out (using headers and then X quantity of elements below).

So, have any of you guys have solved a problem like this before? I'm not really interested in some specific implementation in an X programming language, but mostly in the procedure I could use to accomplish this task (and how should I synchronize these threads to prevent overlapping). I'm using C# just in case some of you really want to share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are `n` items in the list, start each thread `i` at index `i*m`,
where `m = threadCount / n`. Or, in simpler terms, split the list into parts and let each thread handle one part.

Now, let each thread read elements and store it in it's own list.

As soon as you read a header, store the elements you have so far (the previous thread will get these list at the end) and start a new list.

From here it's pretty straight-forward - just read the elements and split whenever you get a header.

When you're done, combine the list you're currently busy with with the first list from the next thread.

If a thread starts on a header, the first list will be empty.

If a thread ends on a header, the current list will be empty, so it will simply take the first list from the next thread.

There are some minor details you should look out for, like how you combine the lists at the end, and like knowing when a list is finalized, or whether it will be combined with other lists, but this should be easy enough.

**Example:**

Input:

```
A
B
C
Header
D
E
F
Header
```

With 4 threads, so each thread gets 2 each:

```
A
B

C
Header

D
E

F
Header
```

Then:

```
Thread Processes
1      A
2      C
3      D
4      F

Thread Processes
1      B
2      Header
3      E
4      Header
```

Here thread `2` will put `C` into its original list and thread `4` will put `F` into its original list, and each will start a new list.

Now we're done, so:

Thread `3` will combine its current list (`{D,E}`) with thread `4`'s original list (`{F}`), so thread `3` will end up with `{D,E,F}`.

Thread `2` will combine its current list (`{}`) with thread `3`'s original list (which is also the current list, since we found no header in thread `3` - `{D,E,F}`), so thread `2` will end up with `{D,E,F}`.

Thread `1` will combine its current list (`{A,B}`) with thread `2`'s original list (`{C}`), so thread `1` will end up with `{A,B,C}`.